LinearLayout in ScrollView cannot scrolled
I want to scroll the '상단 타이틀' space, but the position cannot considered 'scrolling space'
The first scroll position starts with Relative layout.
The style i used (layoutMain uses layout_height: 0dp, and the other styles(layoutTitle, tvTopTitle, tvSubTitle uses layout_height: wrap_content).
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView style="@style/svMain"
        android:background="@color/red">

        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/layoutMain">

            <!--상단 타이틀-->
            <LinearLayout style="@style/layoutTitle"
                android:background="@color/transparent">

                <com.kftc.mobileapi.core.kmutil.KmUtilTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTopTitle"
                    style="@style/title2"
                    android:text="계좌해지 서비스 이용 동의" />

                <com.kftc.mobileapi.core.kmutil.KmUtilTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvSubTitle"
                    style="@style/subTitle2"
                    android:text="아래 사항을 반드시 확인 후 해지신청을 하시기 바랍니다." />
            </LinearLayout>

//The scroll starts with this point. Why????
            <RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_vertical_divider_1dp_gray200" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutCaution"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="24dp"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <com.kftc.mobileapi.core.kmutil.KmUtilTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvCaution"
                    style="@style/cautionTextRegularGray500"
                    android:text="@string/c221"
                    app:wordBreak="keepAll" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbAll"
            style="@style/check_box"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:text="전체 동의"
            android:textColor="@color/colorGray900"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- 하단버튼 -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutBottomBtn"
        style="@style/layoutBottomBtn"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNext"
            style="@style/main03_btn"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="다음" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

I searched the problem with keyword 'linearlayout scroll problem with scrollview(or nestedscrollview)'
But i cant find in my case..
i also tried viewPort=true, but not worked
